# Insert Non-Static Excel Document In OneNote

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote

How do you allow an Excel worksheet to be visualized in OneNote, without making a shallow copy of it.

To be clear, I do not want to copy the Excel worksheet into OneNote, like the simple Insert feature does, I was a link that shows the current content of an Excel document. As in, changes to the original excel document, should be reflected in the OneNote without manually having to reimport it every time.

Comment: If you insert a Hyper Link (Inset, and then Link), the link should reflect the newest content. Hyper Links sure work for web pages - I use this feature all the time. OneNote Desktop version.

Comment: Currently, on my environment with OneNote desktop client, it self is unable to achieve your needs. 

Once the Excel files are inserted into notebooks in visual form, such as via "Insert Spreadsheet", "Insert a Chart or Table", they do not updated with the original files, unless you right-click file name, and then click “Open Original”, you cannot directly see the changes in the original file. I suggest you find some tools to seek help, such as  Auto OneNote.